# Warnings when I try to output my code in C. (place parentheses around assignment to silence this warning, etc)

Tags: c

This is my code. I am getting some weird warning's when I run it and I'm confused on why. Warnings on the bottom. My code will still run and the output is correct, however I still want to understand and fix the warnings thanks. I tried to fix all the warnings, however when I do my code won't output correctly anymore. My program fails. So I am confused. Please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char s1(char *random);
char s2(char *s2_input, int index);
char strfilter(char *random, char *s2_input, char replacement);

int main()
{
    int s1_index = 41;
    char s1_random[s1_index];
    s1(s1_random);
    printf("\ns1 = ");
    puts(s1_random);
    printf("s2 = ");
    int s2_index = 21;
    char s2_input[s2_index];
    s2(s2_input, s2_index);
    if(s2_input[1] == '\0')
    {
        printf("size too small");
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("ch = ");
    char replacement = getchar();
    printf("\n");
    int filter_index = 41;
    strfilter(s1_random, s2_input, replacement);
   printf("\ns1 filtered = ");
   puts(s1_random);
}




char s1(char *random)
{
    int limit = 0;
    char characters;
    while(characters = ('A' + (rand() % 26))) /* random generatro */
    {
        if(limit == 41)
        {
            *(random + 41 - 1) = '\0';
            break;
        }
        *(random + limit) = characters;
        limit++;
    }
}



char s2(char *s2_input, int index)
{
    char array[21] = "123456789012345678901"; /* populated array to make sure no random memory is made */
    char input;
    int count = 0;
    int check = 0;
    while(input = getchar() )
    {
        if(input == '\n')
        {
            *(s2_input + count) = '\0';
            break;
        }

        else if(input < 65 || input > 90)
        {
            printf("invalid input");
            exit(0);
        }

        *(s2_input + count) = input;
        count++;
    }

    index = count;
}

char strfilter(char *random, char *s2_input, char replacement) /* replacement function */
{
    while(*s2_input)
    {
        char *temp = random;

        while(*temp)
        {
            if(*temp == *s2_input)
                *temp = replacement;
            temp++;
        }
        s2_input++;
    }
}
```

**
Error message:
**

```
matthew.c:41:22: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
    while(characters = ('A' + (rand() % 26))) /* random generatro */
          ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
matthew.c:41:22: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
    while(characters = ('A' + (rand() % 26))) /* random generatro */
                     ^
          (                                 )
matthew.c:41:22: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
    while(characters = ('A' + (rand() % 26))) /* random generatro */
                     ^
                     ==
matthew.c:51:1: warning: non-void function does not return a value [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
matthew.c:61:17: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
    while(input = getchar() )
          ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
matthew.c:61:17: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
    while(input = getchar() )
                ^
          (                )
matthew.c:61:17: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
    while(input = getchar() )
                ^
                ==
matthew.c:80:1: warning: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
matthew.c:96:1: warning: non-void function does not return a value [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
5 warnings generated.
```

I tried what the compiler says to do, such as ==, or adding the parenthesis but then my code won't run correctly if I do that. So I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried what the compiler says to do, such as ==, ...

You should not just try any suggestion without understanding it.
Your code is basically correct. You want an assignment.

But assignments in conditions is a very common case of errors. In most cases, there are comparisons used in conditions. The compiler does just warns you that this might be wrong.

Making it a comparison does not make any sense for you.
What you should do instead is using extra brackets:

```
while(characters = ('A' + (rand() % 26)))
```

should be changed into

```
while ((characters = ('A' + (rand() % 26))) != 0)
```

---

In the next message you have an additional problem:

```
while(input = getchar() )
```

Here the reason for the warning is the same: Might be a typo in a comparison.
But this time, you are missing the actual condition. This loop will iterate until `input` will become 0. Normally, you will get `\n` or `EOF` to indicate you reached the end of line or end of file.
Also, `getchar` returns an `int` which means you must use an `int` variable to store the result. Otherwise you could never distinguish value `255` from `EOF`.

This line should be

```
while ((input = getchar()) != EOF )
```

---

Regarding your other type of warning:

```
matthew.c:51:1: warning: non-void function does not return a value [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
```

I think, that is self explaining. If you define a function with a return type, you are supposed to return something.

If you don't need any return value of that function, define it as `void` function.